Connecting Wine App to Linux printer
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I want to print PDF through Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, as far as I know the only product that prints PDF correctly. Virtually everything else gets the margins wrong and tries to print off the edges.
So I installed Adobe Acrobat Reader DC through Wine but I cannot see my local network printer in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
Either, does anyone know how to make a Linux printer visible to a Wine App.
Alternatively, a blog said that you can connect Wine Apps to Linux printers by opening a command line prompt using Alt-f2 and entering "Wine appName", where appName is the full path to the executable.
Unfortunately, When I look in .wine/c_drive/program files/... I cannot find an Adobe folder. So I am unclear where it is installed.
With many thanks in advance for insights
Robin

Did you visit the Wine Site and verify that the app will work the way you want before you installed it? Wine apps and hardware usually do not work. Also this question is missing any Ubuntu info, what version are you using?
